# how to formalize Uml

Tags: uml, z-notation, formalize

Is there a way to convert(formalize) UML to Z notation?
what I mean is that is there any way to re-write UML requirements to a formal language like z?

sorry for my bad English, my native language is not English.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way: you can generate code from UML - so nobody stops you to generate Z from it. Use a template based code generator to easily change the text a model produces. But I suspect you won't find an out of the box solution for it. Nontheless, a short search has brought up [people already doing this](http://irit.fr/~Emmanuel.Dubois/Research/Projects/Previous/AS/Dupuy_UMLZLustre.pdf).

Comment: thank you for your answer, Christian. i don't want any software doing this for me. i just want to do all translation manually but i don't know the rules for translating uml to z. can you help me find a book or any article that describe the rules?

Comment: I don't think that there already is a full fledged spec of that. And I'm almost certain there will be no book about it. There is not much detail in that paper I referenced but it will give you a clue. And maybe you can ask the authors of the paper. Nontheless this would really be research work on your part.

Comment: I guess yours is the best answer and I've to find some clues for my article. thank you Christian.